# Sporadic 504 Bad Gateway Errors

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, rancher

There are multiple apps hosted in my Rancher cluster and I continue to observe sporadic **504 Bad Gateway** errors. The NGINX ingress controller log shows following errors:

These ingress controllers do not show the IP next to them and show following error:

> [error] 314#314: *4 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)
>   while connecting to upstream, client:
>
> These log entries pertain to the 504 Bad Gateway error:
>   controller.go:769] Service
>   "SERVICENAMEREMOVED/ingress-d212988e26a4daf163485eaf33b959fa" does not
>   have any active Endpoint.

I added proxy-connect-timeout and proxy-read-timeout with 120s as value in NGINX config. I then restarted the NGINX ingress controllers, some of which do not come up with an IP assigne.

Comment: what is the client nginx is trying to connect to?

Comment: Please post your config files.